# Printing binary tree level by level with correct format

Tags: c++

I am working on a program where I print the tree level by level.  My problem is that I am trying to have format that is similar to this.

- 5
- 3 9
- x x 7 10
- x x x x x x x 11

where as my format currently is

- 5
- 3 9
- 7 10
- 11

The code I have so far is this

```
void BTree::levelOrder(Node root) {

    queue<Node> queue;
    queue.push(root);

    while(!queue.empty()) {
        Node tempNode=queue.front();
        queue.pop();
        cout<<tempNode.value<<" ";
        if(tempNode.left!=NULL)
            queue.push(*tempNode.left);
        if(tempNode.right!=NULL)
            queue.push(*tempNode.right);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looking at your algorithm, I would rather expect that all nodes are printed in one line: `5 3 9 7 10 11 `.

Comment: Please explain what `x` stands for, and what three is used in your example (draw it).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, OP didn't expose an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

So, I started with a `struct Node` to reproduce OP's problem:

```
struct Node {
  int value;
  Node *left, *right;

  Node(int value, Node *left, Node *right):
    value(value), left(left), right(right)
  { }

  explicit Node(int value):
    Node(value, nullptr, nullptr)
  { }

  ~Node() = default;

  Node(const Node&) = delete;
  Node& operator=(const Node&) = delete;
};
```

... and a function to print nodes (for testing):

```
void printInOrder(const Node &node, int indent = 0)
{
  if (node.left) printInOrder(*node.left, indent + 2);
  std::cout << std::setw(indent) << ""
    << "node" << node.value << '\n';
  if (node.right) printInOrder(*node.right, indent + 2);
}
```

A sample program to reproduce OP's data:

```
int main()
{
  // build tree
  Node node11(11);
  Node node10(10, nullptr, &node11);
  Node node7(7);
  Node node9(9, &node7, &node10);
  Node node3(3);
  Node node5(5, &node3, &node9);
  // dump tree to console
  std::cout << "Print tree inorder:\n";
  printInOrder(node5);
  // done
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Print tree inorder:
  node3
node5
    node7
  node9
    node10
      node11
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ba8724d9bbf2f7b0)</kbd>

The dumped tree looks like described by OP.

Now, I resembled the function of OP:

```
void printLevelOrder(const Node &root)
{
  std::queue<const Node*> queue;
  queue.push(&root);

  while (!queue.empty()) {
    const Node *node = queue.front();
    queue.pop();
    std::cout << "node" << node->value << " ";
    if (node->left) queue.push(node->left);
    if (node->right) queue.push(node->right);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Print tree in levels:
node5 node3 node9 node7 node10 node11
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cdff54f3f24241e3)</kbd>

I'm not sure why OP stated that output would contain 4 lines – there is nothing which prints a newline in any line of OP's code. May be, OP didn't dare to expose his failed attempts. However, as the question is it's inconsistent.

A possible/usual solution is already shown in my `printInOrder()` function: The traversal of nodes has to make additional bookkeeping of the depth. That's actually quite easy as every node can apply its own depth to its children with a simple increment.

While `printInOrder()` is a recursive algorithm (depth can be passed as extra argument), OPs function is an iterative algorithm. Hence, the IMHO simplest solution is to add the bookkeeping of depth to the queue entries:

```
void printLevelOrder(const Node &root)
{
  typedef std::pair<const Node*, int> NodeLevel;
  std::queue<NodeLevel> queue;
  queue.push(std::make_pair(&root, 0));

  while (!queue.empty()) {
    const NodeLevel nodeLevel = queue.front();
    queue.pop();
    std::cout << nodeLevel.second << ": node" << nodeLevel.first->value << " ";
    if (nodeLevel.first->left) {
      queue.emplace(nodeLevel.first->left, nodeLevel.second + 1);
    }
    if (nodeLevel.first->right) {
      queue.emplace(nodeLevel.first->right, nodeLevel.second + 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Print tree in levels:
0: node5 1: node3 1: node9 2: node7 2: node10 3: node11
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8dd0519c90018c50)</kbd>

Now, there is only the last step missing – turn the depth info into sufficient formatting output. Thereby, it has to be considered that the depth of a node itself is not that relevant. Instead, it's more relevant when depth changes (compared to predecessor):

```
void printLevelOrder(const Node &root)
{
  typedef std::pair<const Node*, int> NodeLevel;
  std::queue<NodeLevel> queue;
  queue.push(std::make_pair(&root, 0));

  for (int level = 0; !queue.empty();) {
    const NodeLevel nodeLevel = queue.front();
    queue.pop();
    if (level != nodeLevel.second) std::cout << '\n';
    std::cout << nodeLevel.second << ": node" << nodeLevel.first->value << " ";
    if (nodeLevel.first->left) {
      queue.emplace(nodeLevel.first->left, nodeLevel.second + 1);
    }
    if (nodeLevel.first->right) {
      queue.emplace(nodeLevel.first->right, nodeLevel.second + 1);
    }
    level = nodeLevel.second;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Print tree in levels:
0: node5 
1: node3 1: node9 
2: node7 2: node10 
3: node11
```

What's still missing is the proper indentation.

---

After some discussion with n.m., I gave her/his thoughts a try and modified the sample (again) to achieve the proper formatting. Thereby, I considered non-existing nodes as well (pushing `nullptr`s as placeholders). Due to this, the termination of loop needs another condition – a level which contains `nullptr`s only is remarked by the flag `nextLevelEmpty`:

```
void printLevelOrder(const Node &root)
{
  typedef std::pair<const Node*, int> NodeLevel;
  std::queue<NodeLevel> queue;
  queue.push(std::make_pair(&root, 0));
  bool nextLevelEmpty = false;
  for (int level = -1;;) {
    const NodeLevel nodeLevel = queue.front();
    queue.pop();
    if (level != nodeLevel.second) { // new level
      std::cout << '\n';
      if (nextLevelEmpty) return;
      nextLevelEmpty = true;
    }
    std::cout << std::setw(3);
    if (nodeLevel.first) std::cout << nodeLevel.first->value;
    else std::cout << 'x';
    if (nodeLevel.first) {
      queue.emplace(nodeLevel.first->left, nodeLevel.second + 1);
      queue.emplace(nodeLevel.first->right, nodeLevel.second + 1);
      nextLevelEmpty &= !nodeLevel.first->left && !nodeLevel.first->right;
    } else {
      queue.emplace(nullptr, nodeLevel.second + 1);
      queue.emplace(nullptr, nodeLevel.second + 1);
    }
    level = nodeLevel.second;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Print tree in levels:

  5
  3  9
  x  x  7 10
  x  x  x  x  x  x  x 11
```

I must admit, now, the output looks just like the expected of OP.
It seems n.m. had the better/right feeling.

Comment: No, this doesn't seem to be what OP is requesting. Their format has 1=2^0 entries at level 1, 2=2^1 entries at level 2, 4=2^2 entries at level 3, 8=2^3 entries at line 4. It almost looks like `x` signifies a missing node, and they are all at the beginning of their respective lines only accidentally.

Comment: You need to account for *missing nodes*. I.e. if the root only has a left child and no right child, the second line would look something like `node5 x`.